# I've been developing a VR project for Windows, Mac and Linux. Recently I've had to switch to Android and building I'm getting gradle build errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, sdk, apk

I've attempted creating new keystores and I've followed a few different project setting tutorials but have had no success. Here is the errors logs I'm getting in Unity.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:packageRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
45 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 35 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > value (4976197888) > 0x00000000ffffffffL

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 7s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > value (4976197888) > 0x00000000ffffffffL

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 7s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:packageRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
45 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 35 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <fbd928673be34e73bd91c03b6f2c541c>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <ece5a5820976427dbcd927836361f740>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 412 seconds (411694 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 12 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <ece5a5820976427dbcd927836361f740>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <ece5a5820976427dbcd927836361f740>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar issue where gradle prevented us from building Android APKs. If you are using the default gradle that came with your Unity version, you could try *manually downloading* it from their [releases page](https://gradle.org/releases).
Then, from `Unity > Preferences > External Tools`, untick "Gradle installed with Unity" and Browse to the folder of the downloaded one.

Unity 2022.1 [seems to be compatible](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html) with version 6.1.1, so try and play with releases near to that. Hopefully our workaround also solves your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, unfortunately this work around hasn't fixed my problem, but I do appreciate your answer.